# Modifying Subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm a beginner in matplotlib.
I'm trying to plot various subplot and produce an animation from it.
Issues at hand-

1. I tried to add labels to each graph by looking at few online examples but couldn't succeed. I also gave an legend but it was displayed in the last subplot only.
2. I want make the plots more interactive, as in when i take the cursor on to the plot, it shows x,y co-ordinates.
3. Please suggest on how to proceed with the animation.

As I am using pandas dataframe there are ways to directly plot graphs, but I could proceed on how to animate them. Please feel free to suggest an alternate approach.

Here is the data I am using -

```
 Unnamed: 0     No. of 0runs    No. of 1run     No. of 2runs    No. of 3runs    No. of 4runs    No. of 5runs    No. of 6runs    Seasons
0   0   5279    4654    729     39  1702    6   622     1
1   1   5422    4861    994     60  1320    3   508     2
2   2   5330    5410    910     50  1709    3   587     3
3   3   6675    6203    1021    50  1913    7   639     4
4   4   7092    6839    1113    58  1911    8   731     5
5   5   7294    6589    1179    71  2053    5   681     6
6   6   5361    5190    1009    56  1563    5   715     7
7   7   5043    4928    880     46  1611    1   692     8
8   8   4908    5434    1007    43  1632    4   639     9
```

Here is my code-

```
axs=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
f, axs = plt.subplots(7,figsize=(10,10))

x = seas
axs[0].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 0runs'],c='b',label='No. of zero runs scored in season')
axs[1].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 1run'],c='r',label='No. of one run scored in season')
axs[2].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 2runs'],c='yellow',label='No. of two runs scored in season')
axs[3].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 3runs'],c='orange',label='No. of three runs scored in season')
axs[4].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 4runs'],c='black',label='No. of four runs scored in season')
axs[5].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 5runs'],c='grey',label='No. of five runs scored in season')
axs[6].plot(x, df_of_topruns['No. of 6runs'],c='g',label='No. of six runs scored in season')
```

[image: please take a look subplots]

Comment: I know you specified matplotlib, but you might consider plotly express for something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic form of animation, the animation function is created by repeating the number of x-axes in the animation function to get the values of the data frames in conjunction with each other. Please refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py). For interactive functions, I recommend using another live reilly such as plotly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
 "No. of 0runs" "No. of 1run" "No. of 2runs" "No. of 3runs" "No. of 4runs" "No. of 5runs" "No. of 6runs" Seasons
0 5279 4654 729 39 1702 6 622 1
1 5422 4861 994 60 1320 3 508 2
2 5330 5410 910 50 1709 3 587 3
3 6675 6203 1021 50 1913 7 639 4
4 7092 6839 1113 58 1911 8 731 5
5 7294 6589 1179 71 2053 5 681 6
6 5361 5190 1009 56 1563 5 715 7
7 5043 4928 880 46 1611 1 692 8
8 4908 5434 1007 43 1632 4 639 9
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

axs=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7,figsize=(10,10))
labels = df.columns[:-1].tolist()
x = df['Seasons'].tolist()
colors = ['b','r','y','orange','k','grey','g']

# for i,l in enumerate(labels):
#     axs[i].plot(x, df[l],c=colors[i],label=l+' scored in season')
#     axs[i].set_title(l)
#     axs[i].legend(loc='best')

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.0)

def animate(i):
    for k, l in enumerate(labels):
        axs[k].plot(x[0:i+1], df.loc[0:i, l], c=colors[k],
                    label=l+' scored in season')
        axs[k].set_title(l+' scored in season')
        # axs[k].legend(loc='best')

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=9, repeat=False) 

# anim.save('subplots_ani.gif', writer='pillow')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but the plots are empty. Any suggestion on where I might have done a mistake/s

Comment: Have you tried everything from data to the end of my code?

Comment: I figured it out. the list names I gave we were wrong than the ones I assigned. My bad.

Comment: Has the graph moved? If it moved, please accept the answer.

Comment: The graph didn't move. I was trying to figure it out, so far couldn't do it. Any suggestions. But the rest works fine subplots are printed acurately

Comment: The code has been rechecked and updated. I also updated the image by saving it in GIF format. The code is set to not repeat, but for some reason the GIF is repeating for unknown reasons. Please copy the entire code into your environment and check.